# Facebook app accessing to code in a host inside a private network

Tags: facebook, url, networking, canvas, private

I have configured the Canvas URL of a Facebook app with a domain name that only exists on a private network through a local DNS server: `host1.bussines-local.com`.

However, Facebook was able to retrieve the code and render it in the application canvas. How can it be possible?

I double-checked that the host domain name is not accessible outside the office, and it is not. In fact, our DNS provider does not have any entry for this, and our local DNS server is responding with a unique local IP address (`192.168...`). Moreover, we change the host local IP and the app is not working anymore.

Anyone know how to explain this behaviour?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook canvas is loading you app throw iframe, dose it not?

So when you loading canvas page from computer in your private network canvas iframe can load app because it't available. Your browser is loading it, not facebook, he just direct iframe to url you gave him.